# Open android application from a web page

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-intent, action

I know that for opening android application from a link inside a web page we have to write the following in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="my_scheme" android:host="my_host" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The problem is that I wrote it in the following way:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="my_action"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="my_scheme" android:host="my_host" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I didn't add `android.intent.action.VIEW` and instead I added my own action that i made.
I can't change it because the version is already released.

The question is,

> if there's a way to make the application run from JavaScript or simple
>   html page, maybe by defining the specific action in the page?

Thanks,

Paz.

---

SOLVED:

Thanks to David I found a solution:

```
<a href="intent://my_host#Intent;scheme=my_scheme;action=my_action;end">Link to my stuff</a>
```

Comment: Why can't you just release an update to the market to fix it?

Comment: It will surely solve the problem but i just can't release a new version due to company limitations.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

Make your links look like this:

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=my_action;end">Link to my stuff</a>
```

Also have a look at [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

Comment: Thanks David, what do you mean by intent:#Intent? shouldn't it be my_scheme://my_host or should i write it as it is (intent:#Intent)?

Comment: I've not tried this myself, but it looks like you can launch an Intent from a web browser by using this link format. I don't think your `myscheme://my_host` URL will work in this case because the browser will just create an Intent with `action=android.intent.action.VIEW` and this won't match your Intent filter. You'll need to play with it some. Let me know if you figure it out.

Comment: Hi David, since i'm using host and scheme, this is the full solution: <a href="intent://my_host#Intent;scheme=my_scheme;action=my_action;end">Link to my stuff</a> thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey, if I want to open a web site in google chrome for android how it would be? What should I put in intent? and in my action?

Comment: @MatheusOliveira please open a new question. Asking your question in a comment on this answer isn't the way to get an answer. If you ask a new question you are more likely to get some attention.

Comment: My two cents ....If the link goes inside an HTML email does not work because Gmail remove this kind of hiperlinks.

Comment: i want sent parameters like username and password in intent
how to sent can anyone help?

Comment: @PradeepBishnoi Please open a new question. Asking a question in a comment like this isn't going to get you the help you need. Good luck!

Comment: Docs for `intent:` syntax can be found here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Answer (score 6):

AndroidMainfest declare:

```
<activity android:name="...">
<intent-filter>    
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />    
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data
     android:host="hostName"
     android:path="path"
     android:scheme="schemeName" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

you can let to invoke

```
<a href = "schemeName://hostName/path">
```

or add param similar url in brower

```
<a href = "schemeName://hostName/path?id=1&name=mark">
```

Comment: you can invoke js method to do this. Code as follow:

Answer (score 1):

One way as 林平君 saied,and another way by invoking js method ,code as follow:

```
function openAActivity(){
     window.location = "schemeName://hostName/path"

}
```

this method will send an Android intent to start specified activity.

Answer (score -5):

**1st way:**

```
<html><head></head><body>
<iframe src="YourApp://profile/blabla" width="1px" height="1px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
window.location = "http://YourSite.com/profile/blabla"; }, 4000
                );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

OR 
**2nd way**:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24023048/2165415