# Is there any way to open the android/ios native share dialog from a webpage

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, browser

I'm trying to add a share button to my website which when clicked will open the native share dialog in android/ios where the user can share it via different apps available. I tried the below for android and it did not work from chrome browser

```
intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.SEND;type=text/plain;S.android.intent.extra.TEXT={encoded URL};end
```

Comment: It is not possible on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the website which says more about this: https://paul.kinlan.me/sharing-natively-on-android-from-the-web/

Comment: The URL that I have mentioned is from here... It is not working for me

Comment: Have you tried this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773958/open-android-application-from-a-web-page

Comment: This is to open a specific application from the browser right. I want to open the generic share dialog