# How to solve below failure cases for intent filters( sharing a product in WhatsApp)?

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am trying to share a product in whatsapp.I am able to share product in WhatsApp using `Intent Filters`.
 when I click on that url in WhatsApp, the following cases comes up

> a) if app is installed , Link will redirect you to particular product
>   page in application.
>
> b) if app is not installed ,link should redirect you to play store to
>   install the app

how to check if app is installed or not when user clicks that link in WhatsApp?
How to use deep links to solve above problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is here, just create below method

```
 private boolean isAppInstalled() {
    boolean isAppInstalled;
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        isAppInstalled = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        isAppInstalled = false;
    }
    return isAppInstalled;
}
```

And now call this method on button like this

```
 click_whatsapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isAppInstalled())
                openWhatsApp();
            else
                showMessage("Whatsapp is not install");
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi sir, my question is :  when user clicks the link in  WhatsApp how to check if app is installed in his mobile??

Comment: You have to use deep-linking in your app, and when user click on link, open web-view and then, run script to check app is install or not.

Comment: can u pls tell step by step @Shane

Answer (score 0):

You must use deep linking. Here is more info on [deeplinking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

And step by step procedure on [deeplinking](https://android.jlelse.eu/deep-linking-in-android-46bc61bd9750)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a webpage and url of that page should be shared via whatsApp when product is shared. In that page in javascript you will check if the App is installed in user's phone then open App otherwise redirect to the playStore.
And if your are redirecting to the App you also need to send a token or some parameters to the App for `deep linking` in the App.

You can find a helping link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773958/open-android-application-from-a-web-page)