# javascript check if app exists with a url naming scheme

Tags: javascript, ios, url-scheme

I need a javascript version to open the app if the url scheme exists, so far I know that you can open the app via javascript but how do you check if it exists or not first so I can open the iTunes link.

I've searched but only found half of the solution

[How to open a native iOS app from a web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237031/how-to-open-a-native-ios-app-from-a-web-app)

Answer (score -1):

Luke Wroblewski (UX/UI guru) solved this in a slightly different way ([blogged about here](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1654)) where they drop a cookie when the user signs up that indicates they have the app installed.

There site then checks for the cookie.  It isn't foolproof but it provides a nice user experience when done well.

The article was prompted by this original StackOverflow question: [Is it possible to register a http+domain-based URL Scheme for iPhone apps, like YouTube and Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like/1109200)