# Can we navigate to ios WebView page from javascript page?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, webview, uiwebview

Can we open an ios WebView page from HTML5 using javascript?

I have to redirect to the native ios page from the javascript code on a button click. Is this possible?

I have gone through some links as mentioned below,

[How to open a native iOS app from a web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237031/how-to-open-a-native-ios-app-from-a-web-app)

http://blog.grio.com/2012/07/uiwebview-javascript-to-objective-c-communication.html

But, am not pretty clear with the solutions.

Please help me with your answers and with some proper links.

Comment: Are you able to receive message in ios native code when javascript executed?

Comment: yes, am able to receive messages in ios from javascript. And also from ios to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As you are able to receive/send messages from and to JS. I hope you have `UIWebView` is added as subview in one of your `viewController's` view(self.view). Pass the Java script message to your `ViewContoller` do action here. take for an example you want to present you do it from here.