# Open iOS app from safari browser html code for server side to be passed in URLScheme?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I want to open app from safari browser,for example passed testApp in URLSchemes under URLTypes.what is the deeplink html code from server side for callback URL and for testing app is opening in iPhone or in iPad.

For example for android

```
window.location = "intent://m.google.com/synctest#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.testApp.sync;S.browser_fallback_url=http://m.google.com;end;"
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237031/how-to-open-a-native-ios-app-from-a-web-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply use the URLScheme you defined. Say you defined `MyApp` and wanted to go to the homePage and pass in data, you might use something like this:

`MyApp://home?customVar1=value1&customVar2=value2`