# redirect to ios application using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, deep-linking

i have read a lot of stack-over-flow Q&A and blogs about deep linking, the way i found convenient was to use header() function in my php code and use url within it to redirect. But when i put `myApp://` in header function like this

```
header('Location: myApp://');
```

as redirect link it says

> cannot open the page because too many redirects occur

then did some research and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237031/how-to-open-a-native-ios-app-from-a-web-app)

then according to the link, i used javascript method as

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">window.location="360VUZ://";</script>';
```

to achieve the same 
still this doesn't work as it changed the whole url i needed to open the app
it says

> The requested URL /subFolder/myApp:// was not found

now i am not getting how the path is appending itself, all i need is to hit this

```
myApp://
```

url to open my application

any type of help or suggestion is appreciated ! thanks in advance!!

EDIT:

specifically when i am using JS to open app, it says

> The requested URL /subFolder/myApp:// was not found on this server.

so all i need to do is somehow delete/remove the prefix path as it is finding the app on the server not on device and hit only 'myApp://', but still dont know how!? please help me!

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237031/how-to-open-a-native-ios-app-from-a-web-app

Comment: already read out the whole thing even used the meta tag too, but still not working!

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 9.2, Apple deprecated the ability to launch apps via URI schemes in favor of Universal Linking. Consequently, this approach that you are exploring no longer works.

Your options are to set up Universal Linking on your own or to leverage a third party service like branch.io.