# how do I open a native app from a webpage

Tags: javascript, web, native

Is it posible to open a native IOS app from a webpage. In my case I want to open https://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/barcode-scanners/id504201315?mt=8

I have heard of URL schemes, that can trigger apps.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [something like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237031/how-to-open-a-native-ios-app-from-a-web-app)

Comment: jep.
I also found this
https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/

but what for this specific app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So you can use URL schemes.

[Here](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/) is a list of many apps. But it all comes down to the individual app, if they provide a URL scheme.

For me, I could do like this

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="pic2shop://scan?callback=https3A%2F%2FMyUrl">Scan</a>
```

This enables me to start a barcode scanner app, scan a barcode, and get a callback with the extracted number.